# Jenkins build failing

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins

I had to upgrade angular version from 5 to 8 in my application. But after the upgrade Jenkins build is failing. I am getting the error message saying I need to upgrade node.js to v10.9 or greater. But I am already using nodejs version 10.16.3 in my system. So, I want to know where do I need to upgrade the nodejs?

Comment: You will need to upgrade node.js on your jenkins server ie. globally.
https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm

Comment: Did you following all the guide from https://update.angular.io/#5.0:8.0 ???

Comment: Yes I followed the guide and it is getting compiled successfully in my local machine. But the build is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the latest/upgrade the version in your Jenkins server system.
You can include these command in the build job -

```
npm i -g npm@latest            
npm i node@latest
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Actually I'm working in angular and don't have much knowledge about Jenkins. Can you specify where I need to Include these commands?

Comment: Jenkins have a specific jobs to build/run/deploy the whole application, check the job  in which the angular app is getting compiled, in that job you will have to include these commands as well(just before you run the `npm install` and other commands).

Comment: You can also follow this https://medium.com/@vs28031996/upgrade-from-angular-4-5-to-angular-7-49e505b8e1fd for any upgrade reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the below commands in your Jenkins slave(s).

```
 # Clean the cache
 sudo npm cache clean
 # Remove the old one
 sudo npm remove -g @angular/cli
 # Install angular 8.0.2
 sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@8.0.2
```